# CSS imageviewer: Image rotation (and scaling)

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to have a simplistic image viewer in a react project of mine.
Is there a way to implement rotation (and ideally scaling) without referencing the current dimensions of the DOM node in JS?

So far I tried something like this (reduced case/taken from my jsfiddle):

```
function getTransform() {
    switch (rotation) {
    case 90: return { 
        transform: 'translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg)', 
      'transform-origin': 'bottom left'
     };
    case 180: return {
        transform: 'translate(100%, -100%) rotate(180deg)', 
      'transform-origin': 'bottom left'
    }
    case 270: return { 
        transform: 'translateX(-100%) rotate(270deg)', 
      'transform-origin': 'top right'
     };
     default: return {
        transform: 'none'
     }
  }
}
```

and apply that as styles on my element. Unfortunately that doesn't work. While I can use the 100%/relative values for Y (i.e. 90 degrees works, 180 degrees works for the Y axis at least), I cannot use it to translate the X axis - parts of the image are offscreen.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7huLa8e1/2/

Is there a way to use relative values alone or do I have to grab the DOM node and use width/height in absolute pixel values to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your problem is that the image overflows the container to the right in an unspecified size.

We need to get around this. My idea is to float right the image inside the container. we will need a clearfix to keep it taking the correct size.

I have redone the jquery to works with css classes, since it is the easiest way to modify the child (the image)

```js
var rotation = 0;



function rotate(deg) {
 rotation = (360 + rotation + deg) % 360;
  $('#image-viewer').attr('class',  'rotate' + rotation);
}

$(function(){
$('#rotateLeft').click(
 function(event) {
   rotate(-90);
  }
);

$('#rotateRight').click(
 function(event) {
   rotate(90);
  }
);

});
```

```css
#image-viewer {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid red 2px;
}

.image-viewer-root {
  height: 100vh;
}

.image-viewer-viewport {
  height: 90%;
  overflow: auto;
}


.rotate90 {
  transform:  rotate(90deg) translate(0%, -100%);
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.rotate180 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.rotate180 img {
  float: right;
}



.rotate270 {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0%) rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.rotate270 img {
  float: right;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-viewer-root">
  <nav class="toolbar navbar navbar-dark bg-faded">
    <div class="nav navbar-nav">
      <button id="rotateLeft" class="btn nav-item">RotateLeft</button>
      <button id="rotateRight" class="btn nav-item">RotateRight</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="image-viewer-viewport">
    <div id="image-viewer">
      <img src="https://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```